# Can a relation be transitive without a direct relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Say there is a set {x,y,z} and there is a relation R {(x,y), (y,z)}. Does that make the relation transitive, as x=y and y=z, making x=z? Or is it not transitive because there is no (x,z) relation?

Comment: It is not because there is no (x,z) in the relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example: Father-son relation is not transitive. Eg: *John is the father of Jack* and *Jack is the father of Bob* **does not imply** *John is the father of Bob*.

Another example: Natural sibling relation is transitive. Eg: *Jack is Jill's sibling* and *Jill is Jane's sibling* **implies** *Jack is Jane's sibling*.

In a transitive relation, $x R y \land y R z$ implies $x R z$. In the absence of $xRz$, $R$ cannot be construed as being transitive.